# script não funciona como o esperado

Tags: javascript

Achei esse script que quando adicionado no rodapé de uma página do meu site, ele pega o parâmetro SRC da URL dessa página e adiciona no final de todos links da página. Funciona.
Porém, eu queria que ele adicionasse o parâmetro somente em **UM LINK ESPECÍFICO** da página. Por exemplo, no link de compra. É possível fazer algum ajuste no código abaixo?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const urlParams= new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('src');

const todosLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < todosLinks.length; i++) {
todosLinks[i].href = todosLinks[i].href + '&src=' + myParam;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisas de saber o id desse link e depois podes usar este código.

```
const linkCompra = document.getElementById('link-compra');
linkCompra.href = linkCompra.href + '&src=' + myParam;
```